# Freeform Form expired error in Google Chrome only

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, csrf, chrome

I am using an {exp:freeform:form} tag for contact requests and am getting this error when submitting the form in Google Chrome only:

"This form has expired. Please refresh and try again."

Because this is EE's CSRF protection error, I tried disabling CSRF protection in my config file and submitting the form. This works, but I dont' want to leave it off permanently.

```
$env_config['disable_csrf_protection'] = "y";
```

The odd thing is, why would this only happen in Chrome and not Firefox, Safari, etc.

Could it be a Cookie issue?

The site is using:
EE 2.9.2
Freeform 4.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExpressionEngine 2.9.3 officially addressed and resolved some common issues with CSRF. I strongly suggest you upgrade to EE 2.9.3 or greater to resolve or rule out that issue. :)

"CSRF tokens stored in cookies refresh with page refresh." - [ExpressionEngine 2.9.3 Change Log](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/about/changelog.html#version-2-9-3)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I'll upgrade as soon as possible and post back with the results.

Comment: hmm...I upgraded EE to the latest version 2.10.3 and Freeform to 4.2.4 and am still experiencing the same issue in Chrome.

Comment: Is there anything else I can look into at this point after upgrading?

Comment: Can you duplicate this from another computer in Chrome? :)

Comment: I've been able to duplicate this on another computer in Chrome. If my cookie is set for .example.com and the url is www.example.com could that cause any issues?

Comment: Curious, if I should pursue submitting this as a support request as that may be a better medium for this type of question?

Comment: Sure, that would be better.